# Emphasize the SplitContainer

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way (without including new controls in the project :) to customize the SplitContainer in order to visually indicate to the user that there is a splitter container (I have an horizontal one), and not just some space between controls?

[image]

PS.

I would like do not modify the colors. Also I find 3D Border ugly.. perhaps fill-in a "picture" in the split delimiter space?

Comment: like changing its color? should be possible, look at the control's properties :)

Comment: BorderStyle, backcolor, bordersize or container or inner panels

Comment: @Davide Piras, hungryMind: see my PS in the post )

Answer (score 1):

Select the SplitContainer and change BorderStyle to Fixed3D to get this effect:

[image]

Comment: ) yes, I tried this. my application style is flat one, so I could use flat mode... I'd like of only the splitter be in 3D, not the panels. Also, if the splitter is Horizontal is "less evident" that for a vertical one...

Comment: I'm unsure how to achieve this without adding any more controls. I would consider adding panels and dock-fill them, and then experiment with their appearance-settings.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to customize that control still using that control (make sense), and provided properties are not enough for your needs you can always override the `WindowProc` and handle `WM_PAINT` message yourself for that control, so you can draw whatever you want :)

Comment: yes if you need to add a picture and this is not already supported and the control does not allow you to easily handle the OnPaint event, you can always catch the Windows Messages like WM_PAINT and do what you need to do in there :) basic Windows APIs programming still valid in .NET :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `BackColor` property to something else, but then change the two inner panels to different colors:

```
splitContainer1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
splitContainer1.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
splitContainer1.Panel1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
splitContainer1.Panel2.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```

To finish the look (I know you said not adding other controls, so ignore this part if that's mandatory), place the splitContainer inside a panel and Dock.Fill it with the parent panel having these properties:

```
splitParent.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
splitParent.Padding = new Padding(1);
```

Result:

[image]